# How to append/update one to many relationship's property values

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I want to involve CoreData in my project, but firstly I need to understand it, so I try to start a simple project to practice to see how it works. Here I have a one-many relationship models, Playlist and Song.

Get questions as below, your help is appreciated!

1. Now Playlist has the one-many relationship with Song, but should I also put Song's playlist property as one-many since a song could be in different playlist? For now it is one-one relationship for Song's playlist.
2. The song property of Playlist is NSSet type, how could I append the same Playlist like playlist01's song property as (playlist01, [song1, song2, song3...]) but not add a new row of Playlist entity (playlist01, [song1]), (playlist02, [song2])...
3. If I delete a song in the Song entity, if it will auto delete the related song in Playlist's song property? Or I need to implement it manually?

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        insert(playlistName: "playlist01", songName: "Love", artistName: "Tylor Swift")
        insert(playlistName: "playlist01", songName: "Just Dance", artistName: "Lady Gaga")
        insert(playlistName: "playlist02", songName: "Numb", artistName: "Linkin Park")
    }

    func insert(playlistName: String, songName: String, artistName: String) {
        let playlist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Playlist", into: context) as! Playlist
        let song = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: context) as! Song

        song.songName = songName
        song.artistName = artistName

        playlist.name = playlistName
        playlist.addToSong(song)


        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Save OK!")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not save: \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Query(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            let fetchObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for item in fetchObjects {

                print("=====================================================")
                print("Playlist name:", item.name ?? "No Playlist name")
                for songItem in item.song! {
                    var songName = (songItem as! Song).songName
                    print("song name:", songName)
                }

                // print("artist name:", item.song?.artistName ?? "No artistName")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not query: \(error)")
        }
    }



    @IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            let fetchObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for item in fetchObjects {
                context.delete(item)
                print("Deleted")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not delete: \(error)")
        }

    }
}
```

/ / / OutPut, yes, I know it is not correct, now it just insert a new row to the entity Playlist. My idea is to create a playlistPool:[String] to store the playlist names, then compare if equal then append the song into Playlist else insert a new row to the table.

```
=====================================================
Playlist name: playlist01
song name: Optional("Love")
=====================================================
Playlist name: playlist01
song name: Optional("Just Dance")
=====================================================
Playlist name: playlist02
song name: Optional("Numb")
```

/ / / According to Joakim Danielson's comment, I update my code to add a fetch to get playlist01 object in viewDidLoad then add a song to playlist01.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        insert(playlistName: "playlist01", songName: "Love", artistName: "Tylor Swift")
        insert(playlistName: "playlist01", songName: "Just Dance", artistName: "Lady Gaga")
        insert(playlistName: "playlist02", songName: "Numb", artistName: "Linkin Park")

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name= 'playlist01' ", "")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        let song = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: context) as! Song
        song.songName = "Moon"
        song.artistName = "bbb"

        do {
            let fetchObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for item in fetchObjects {

                item.addToSong(song)
                print("=====================================================")
                print("Playlist name:", item.name ?? "No Playlist name")
                for songItem in item.song! {
                    let songName = (songItem as! Song).songName
                    print("song name:", songName)
                }

                // print("artist name:", item.song?.artistName ?? "No artistName")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not query: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func insert(playlistName: String, songName: String, artistName: String) {
        let playlist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Playlist", into: context) as! Playlist
        let song = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: context) as! Song

        song.songName = songName
        song.artistName = artistName

        playlist.name = playlistName
        playlist.addToSong(song)


        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Save OK!")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not save: \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Query(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            let fetchObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for item in fetchObjects {

                print("=====================================================")
                print("Playlist name:", item.name ?? "No Playlist name")
                for songItem in item.song! {
                    let songName = (songItem as! Song).songName
                    print("song name:", songName)
                }

                // print("artist name:", item.song?.artistName ?? "No artistName")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not query: \(error)")
        }
    }



    @IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            let fetchObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for item in fetchObjects {
                context.delete(item)
                print("Deleted")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not delete: \(error)")
        }

    }
}
```

/ / / Now the output: playlist01's property is appended. Well the code is quite messy, I just to want to see if it is working. I will improve that in my real project/app:)

```
=====================================================
Playlist name: playlist01
song name: Optional("Moon")
song name: Optional("Love")
=====================================================
Playlist name: playlist01
song name: Optional("Just Dance")
song name: Optional("Moon")
```

Comment: 1. Yes make it a many-to-many relationship 2. Just call `playlist1.addToSong()` for each song object (if I understood correctly) 3. Core Data handles it for you

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, thx, I already change it to many-to-many relationship, but for 2nd question, do u mean I need to fetch the playlist1 first? Then addToSong() for that playlist1. Also e.g. if I change the property of entity Song, should I change the property of Playlist too, or just do it in one side is ok.

Comment: If you’re assigning a song to a playlist then you need that object. You only need to change one property as long you have defined the relationship in both directions in your model.

Comment: If you're learning to develop, there's a hell of a lot to be said for (a) learning standard sql, and then indeed (b) use MySql inside your iPhone app (mysql works flawlessly inside iPhone - it's right there).  once you're really expert with sql, core data is nothing, 2 minutes work.  conversely, learning core data won't "do anything for you" in computing generally.  Enjoy!

Comment: I update my code to add a fetch to get playlist01 object then add a song to playlist01, it is worked. And good to know that changing one property is enough because the relationship of CoreData is really killing me recent days... I do search a lot but can not combine all of them as one until now.

Comment: @Fattie, unfortunately I do know how to use SQL... But indeed it takes me several days to understand the relationship of CoreData not 2 mins:( Im not so clever. I could say they are different, SQL using the primary key to link each table, but in CoreData, it simply doesn't have it and to use relationship instead if I'm understood correctly.

Comment: Core Data manages and persist the model layer and it is not a database layer so it is not necessary to know Sql to use Core Data. In fact many judging by the questions here many developer fails to take full advantage of Core Data because they try to treat it as a database tool.

Comment: Here is my video links of Coredata relationship please check this :-
1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkEQKYqBf38&t=2178s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km_YyJgALrs&t=2s

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's totally correct.  But let me put it this way:  anyone trying to learn anything about computers, should become expert in SQL before doing much else!

Comment: @Fattie I completely disagree :)